# Best way to limit height:100% ... - 50px?

Tags: html, css

What is should be the best way to limit something like this?

height : 100% , but I need 100% - 50px !!! , how do I calculate that or address that problem?

Thanks in advance!

Marco,

Comment: You can't do that with standard CSS - there's no support for "math" like that. You can use things like jquery to dynamically remove the 50px later on, but you can't do it with pure css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, mandel99's answer is the best, `calc` function is exactly the solution. But if you need to support browsers that don't support it, you can try following workarounds:

1) pure CSS2.1 way — absolute positioning:

```
.container {
   height: 100%; /* all parents also need to have 100% height, including html */
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 50%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

2) `box-sizing: border-box` and transparent border:

```
.element {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* can be removed when Firefox 28- becomes outdated */
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 100%;
   border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

As all 'hacks', both have their limitations, but there are situations when they help.

Answer (score 5):

IF you need the 50px on the bottom just drag a container up 50px with a negative margin and give it 100% height.  Something like this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>100% minus 50px</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background: #000;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #almost100 {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #container {
            background: #f08;
            min-height: 100%;
            margin-top: -50px;
        }
        p {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #footer {
            background: #f00;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="almost100">
            <p>:)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mark123 This will hide the content in the last 50px of the page.

Comment: @H - It's just the concept, the code isn't tested.  I'll rewrite it.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Here's a live link with the edited code listed above: http://imaginekitty.com/cssExamples/almost100.html

Comment: put it up on jsfiddle.net and i will show you. You can't see from your example because you do not have any content to see if it is hidden in the last 50px

Comment: It expands with the content pushing the 50px footer down as more content is added.  Link with more content: http://imaginekitty.com/cssExamples/almost100MoreContent.html

Comment: Go to IE and try it out in quirkmode. just put couple of lines, you will see what i mean. JQuery is the only cross browser compatible way to properly do this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/imaginekitty/xn77c/ Sorry it took so long I had to create an account as I've never used jsfiddle before.

Comment: Why would I purposely put it in quirksmode?

Comment: Older browsers are locked to quirks mode, If you want to ensure cross browser compatibility, you must test with quirks mode. it's there for a reason. You also have top padding of 50px which will create more issue for your header.

Comment: Please explain the issue with the padding.  The padding is there to compensate for the negative margin.  Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imaginekitty/qVnwJ/

Answer (score 2):

try "calc" method in css:

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Now ( 14.04.2014 ) 
Is supported on all major browsers (only opera mini it does not)
http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's the thing. There is no 1:1 ratio for converting from Pixel to Percentages or the other way around. There are a lot of variables to consider. And each case is different.

So, what you *can* do is this:

```
height: 98.5%; /* (you can use your own numbers, obviously) */
```

That will give you much more freedom to work with when using Percentages in CSS. I'm sure there may be another way, but if there is, I don't know about it and this is the best I can do for you right now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript for this. 
Let's say you already have `<div id="mydiv"></div>` set to 100%;

To subtract 50px you can use jQuery and do

```
var d = $('#mydiv').height(); //get the div height
var final = parseInt(d-50); //subtract 50
```

Then you can apply the new height with -50px back to your mydiv by doing

```
$('#mydiv').height(final); //assign the new height
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily if you're willing to use a table; the html is ugly but it'll work. Set the table height to 100%, two rows, put your content in a cell in the first row, and set the height of the cell in the bottom row to 50px. Then, if you need something in the bottom 50px, either put it in that bottom row, or position a div on top of it, position absolute, bottom:0px.

```
<table cellpadding=”0” cellspacing=”0” style=”height:100%”>
<tr><td>Put your stuff here</td></tr>
<tr><td style=”height:50px;”>Bottom content goes here</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this help you?

```
min-height:100%;height:auto !important;height:50px;
```

or

```
min-height:50px;height:auto !important;height:100%;
```

not shure if it goes on first or seccond way! to sleepy i am to go try it! so you go try it yourself :D

Hope it helps!